# SQL why sp is slower than query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

It may look simple question but i really need help. I have been trying this for two days.

I am passing **userid** as parameter to stored procedure and using that **userid** i am retrieving **companyid** to use it in another query.

```
CREATE PROC spXXXXXXX
@UserID INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CompanyID INT
SET @CompanyID =(SELECT CompanyID FROM User WHERE UserID=@UserID)

SELECT
            DISTINCT (U.UserID),
            U.UserName, 
            U.FirstName,
            U.LastName,
            C.CompanyName,
            U.Email,
            U.IsActive,
    FROM    
            [User] U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            Company C
        ON
            C.CompanyID =U.CompanyID 
    WHERE   
            U.CompanyID=@CompanyID 
END
```

It takes more than 30 seconds to execute.but if i pass the value directly to the query then it takes 1 second only. the **SET** takes more time to execute.

So i tried to use CTE to speed up the query but there was no luck. same time only.

```
;WITh cte(CompanyID)
        as
        (
        SELECT CompanyID FROM [User] WHERE UserID=@CurrentUserId
        ) 

   SELECT
            DISTINCT (U.UserID),
            U.UserName, 
            U.FirstName,
            U.LastName,
            C.CompanyName,
            U.Email,
            U.IsActive,
    FROM    
            [User] U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            Company C
        ON
            C.CompanyID =U.CompanyID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            cte CS
        ON  
            CS.CompanyID =C.CompanyID
    WHERE   
            U.CompanyID=CS.CompanyID
```

Its still taking 27 seconds to return 31 records. if i pass the value directly means it takes only one sec.. What am i doing wrong?.

Comment: What do the execution plans show?

Comment: I guess the engine is using the wrong plans to begin with. Did you try altering the stored procedure with `ALTER PROC spXXXXXXX WITH RECOMPILE` option. ?

Comment: Could be [parameter sniffing](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options), it is basically impossible to say without seeing the execution plans though.Simplest way to check would be mark the procedure for recompilation (`EXECUTE sp_recompile N'spXXXXXXX'`), rather than forcing it to recompile with every execution (as `WITH RECOMPILE` would)

Comment: this queries aren't the same and where does your `@companyID` comes from in the second example?

Comment: @Richard i can see the execution plan. What should i do with that.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I recompiled it.still slow

Comment: @GarethD Tried that. still no use

Comment: @Aツ Sorry tying mistake that was CS.CompanyID.. I edited it now.

Comment: this might be dirty but if you just need the companyname, you could select it in a separate query. then you avoid the join and it might increase the performance.

Comment: You should add the execution plans to your question as images. It would probably also be useful to add details of any indexes you have on the tables. How many records do you have in each table?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely suffering from an implicit OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) by using the intermediate variables.  See [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/stored-procedure-execution-with-parameters-variables-and-literals/).  The optimizer is not providing a good plan for your query this way.

You would have the same issue with the second query if `@CurrentUserID` is a variable and not a parameter.  Try this query to see if it will perform better:

```
CREATE PROC spXXXXXXX
    @UserID INT
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    U.UserID,
    U.UserName, 
    U.FirstName,
    U.LastName,
    C.CompanyName,
    U.Email,
    U.IsActive,
FROM [User] CU -- current user
INNER JOIN [User] U -- users with same company
ON      CU.CompanyID = U.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN Company C
ON      C.CompanyID =U.CompanyID 
WHERE   CU.[UserID] = @UserID
```

You may still have some issues with Parameter Sniffing, but this should help the optimizer generate a better execution plan for your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it helps... Creating a local variable for the user, to avoid parameter sniffing.

```
declare @local_UserId int 
  select @local_UserId = @UserID

  DECLARE @CompanyID INT
    SET @CompanyID =(SELECT CompanyID FROM User WHERE UserID=@local_UserId)
```